# Header is not showing with RelativeLayout

Tags: android, listview, android-relativelayout

I am using a ListView to show a standings table but the header is not showing:

**This is the main layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <!-- Team name -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_name"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@string/dash"
            android:textColor="@color/holo"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <!-- Games played -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/games_played"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@string/dash"
            android:textColor="@color/holo"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:typeface="sans" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0px" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**And this is the ListView layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <!-- Position -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/position"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/holo"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <!-- Team image -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/team_image_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/position"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/team_image"
            android:layout_width="48dip"
            android:layout_height="48dip"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/team_image_description"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Team name -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/team_name"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/team_image_layout"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/holo"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <!-- Games played -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/games_played"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/team_name"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/holo"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:typeface="sans" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The ListView is displayed but not the headers
What I am dong wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should put the `ListView` **below** the `LinearLayout` , your xml layout should be like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_header"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <!-- Team name -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_name"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@string/dash"
            android:textColor="@color/holo"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <!-- Games played -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/games_played"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@string/dash"
            android:textColor="@color/holo"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:typeface="sans" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout_header" <!-- this attribute will put the ListView below the Layout which has the id layout_header -->
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0px" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it happens :p, mark the answer as the correct one by checking the green mark below the upvote/downvote buttons :)